# std::chrono::duration_cast - is GCC implementation bugged?

Tags: c++, gcc, std, c++-chrono

I think i've found a bug in GCC implementation of std::chrono::duration_cast. Could anyone please confirm me this?

Test code:

```
using Ticks = std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio_multiply<std::chrono::nanoseconds::period, std::ratio<100>>>;

using dur = typename std::chrono::system_clock::duration;

int main() 
{

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> earliest {std::chrono::duration_cast<dur>(
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Ticks>::max().time_since_epoch())};

    auto ticks = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Ticks>::max().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::cout << "Ticks: " << ticks << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof(earliest.time_since_epoch().count()) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Microseconds: " << earliest.time_since_epoch().count() << "\n";

    std::time_t t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(earliest);
    std::cout << "earliest:\n" << std::ctime(&t);
}
```

Output with clang 3.8 is:

```
Ticks: 9223372036854775807
8
Microseconds: 922337203685477580
earliest:
Sun Sep 14 02:48:05 31197
```

Output with GCC 7.1 is:

```
Ticks: 9223372036854775807
8
Microseconds: -100
earliest:
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
```

Am i wrong?

Comment: clang in version 3.8 works in the same way as gcc on my computer

Comment: Forgot to mention that the test was done with coliru platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug, you're just causing a signed overflow, hence undefined behaviour. Indeed, your code is relying on platform dependent assumptions (the system clock period and rep type) that just happens to fail in the gcc test case.

At the moment of writing, the `system_clock` used by Coliru's GCC environment has a nanosecond duration period of long type, that in turn have the same size of long long.

So, when you `duration_cast<system_clock::duration>` a `time_point<system_clock,Ticks>::max().time_since_epoch()`

you are casting a duration of `numeric_limits<Ticks::rep>::max()` periods of 100 nanoseconds each into a nanosecond duration of long type, resulting in something equivalent to `numeric_limits<Ticks::rep>::max()*100` that clearly overflows (your two-complement signed implementation happens to wrap, resulting in `-100`; anyway, this is still undefined behaviour).

Conversely, on my clang copy, `system_clock` has a microsecond duration period of long long type, resulting in a duration cast equivalent ot `numeric_limits<Ticks::rep>::max()/10`.

Comment: ubsan can detect signed integer overflows at run time by the way… One of my colleagues found a very similar (negative) overflow where `std::chrono::microseconds::min()` was converted to nanoseconds, by using ubsan.